# Is it possible to run multiple same program simultaneously in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, multithreading

I have a program that simulates some hardware behavior and hardware operation. The program will accept input for different hardware devices and simulate it.

Now I want to perform a test where multiple hardware simulates together. Is it possible that I can make the program runs like this? For example, the same program runs 5 copies of it and simultaneously.

Similar to threads in C# I think. Can NodeJS achieve the same thing? I searched on multi-threading on NodeJS but not much came out of it.

Appreciates if anyone can help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Understanding how Node handles concurrency under the hood can be incredibly daunting and rewarding at the same time. Essentially, Node runs on a single thread and internally uses a thread pool.

So does it mean it can handle only one request at a time ? Yes and No Sir.

The answer to your question depends on what kind of task you're running. If it's Database I/O, then yes, node can handle several requests in parallel. You can use async/await to achieve this.

However, if your task is computational i.e CPU intensive which I assume it is, then it will block the main thread until that computation is done. In other words, it will only process one request at a time.

You can read the below article to understand as to what qualifies as a blocking/non blocking operation.
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/